# While installing browser-sync I am getting two warnings and it could not be installed

Tags: browser-sync

```
C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\browser-sync -> C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browser-sync\dist\bin.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ browser-sync@2.26.10
updated 1 package in 8.344s
```

Comment: `Unsupported platform` you can't do this in win

Comment: Can you suggest some alternatives of Browser-sync which can work on Windows?